# Soft db error handling for duplicate entries? -- Rails 3.1 newbie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

If a user tries to enter a duplicate entry into a table, they get a full page nasty error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique in Admin::MerchantsController#add_alias

Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '2-a' for key 'merchant_id': ..
```

Is there a way to give a flash message instead like "This record already exists"?

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=24544) from railsforum can help you

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend checking for the uniqueness and specifically responding to this validation rule via a flash message, this conventionally should be handled by the form's error messages instead.

Nonetheless, in the controller actions for creating and updated you could wrap the conditional block which decides where to send the user, with a check for uniqueness first:

```
def create
  @merchant = Merchant.new params[:merchant]
  if Merchant.where(:merchant_id => @merchant.id).count > 0
    flash[:error] = "The merchant id #{@merchant.id} already exists"
    render :create    # amend this to :update when applying to the update action
  else
    # your normal generated save and render block
  end
end
```

This isn't the cleanest way of achieving your goal, but I think it'll be easiest to understand.

Would really recommend the model validations and form error messages instead, which if you are usung the generated scaffolding, all you need to do is add a model validation and the form throw out the error messages to the user for you:

```
# app/models/merchant.rb
class Merchant < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :merchant_id
end
```

Comment: Having the models check for uniqueness still throws a full page error (albeit a slightly better wording on these errors).